# Ember-data with complex url

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Killed few days trying to resolve this issue.

Normally I use Embers conversion to get a model from store:

```
OlaMagic.DashboardIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.findAll('number');


    }

});
```

This would resolve to GET => 
DS: RESTAdapter#ajax GET to http://localhost:8080/api/numbers

**But I CANNOT find a ways to execute a request against this URL:
http://localhost:8080/api/profiles/:profile_id/workspaces**

BTW
http://localhost:8080/api/profiles/:profile_id does not return a key to iterate over workspaces. The only way to get all workspaces is via direct url.

Comment: Is `:profile_id` the current logged in user or any arbitrary user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this isn't a normal way for the REST adapter to build URLs. At minimum you would need to make a special adapter for the workspaces model then you'll need to override `urlForQuery` (if it's request specific) and specify and move some of the logic that's inside of `_buildURL` into that.

**adapters/workspaces.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  urlForQuery: function(query, modelName){
    var url = ['api','profiles', query.profile, 'workspaces'];
    delete query.profile;
    var host = this.get('host');
    var prefix = this.urlPrefix();

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url && url.charAt(0) !== '/') {
      url = '/' + url;
    }

    return url;
  }
});
```

Then you do something like this:

```
OlaMagic.DashboardIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.query('workspace', {profile: 1});
  }
});
```

This will generate a request to **/api/profiles/1/workspaces**.

If you're only ever requesting workspaces on the current user then it could probably be enough to just overriding `init` on the adapter for `workspaces` and setting a deeper `namespace` on it on authentication.

Comment: oh great. it worked. thanks. btw it seems was using 1.0.0-beta and it didn't have query() method.

Comment: @Macchiatow Cool, don't forget to accept the answer if it's correct. :)

Comment: HI, one more quetion. Having newer version of ember would allow to do {profile: 1}. ""Error while processing route: dashboard.index" "Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined". Seems I have to pass ':profile_id', but then how adapter going to parse it from params if params are not in the scope. @KitSunde

Comment: @Macchiatow Did you ever figure out how to resolve the "Assertion Failed..." error?